# Convert an image to base64 without using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, base64, microsoft.ink

**First, a little background:**

I apologize ahead of time for the long-winded nature of this preface; however, it may assist in providing an alternate solution that is not specific to the nature of the question.

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses embedded WinForm UserControls.  These control provide "ink-over" support to TabletPCs through the `Microsoft.Ink` library.  They are an unfortunate necessity due to an IE8 corporate standard; otherwise, HTML5 Canvas would be the solution.

Anyway, an image URL is passed to the `InkPicture` control through a `<PARAM>`.

```
<object VIEWASEXT="true" classid="MyInkControl.dll#MyInkControl.MyInkControl" 
        id="myImage"  name="myImage" runat="server">
    <PARAM name="ImageUrl" value="http://some-website/Content/images/myImage.png" />
</object>
```

The respective property in the `UserControl` takes that URL, calls a method that performs an `HttpWebRequest`, and the returned image is placed in the `InkPicture`.

```
public Image DownloadImage(string url)
    {
        Image _tmpImage = null;

        try
        {
            // Open a connection
            HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

            // use the default credentials
            _HttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Request response:
            System.Net.WebResponse _WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Open data stream:
            System.IO.Stream _WebStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream();

            // convert webstream to image
            _tmpImage = Image.FromStream(_WebStream);

            // Cleanup
            _WebResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error
            throw ex;
        }

        return _tmpImage;
    }
```

***Problem***

This works, but there's a lot of overhead in this process that significantly delays my webpage from loading (15 images taking 15 seconds...not ideal).  Doing `Image img = new Bitmap(url);` in the `UserControl` does not work in this situation because of FileIO Permission issues (Full trust or not, I have been unsuccessful in eliminating that issue).

---

***Initial Solution***

Even though using `canvas` is not a current option, I decided to test a solution using it.  I would load each image in javascript, then use `canvas` and `toDataUrl()` to get the base64 data.  Then, instead of passing the URL to the `UserControl` and have it do all the leg work, I pass the base64 data as a `<PARAM>` instead.  Then it quickly converts that data back to the image.

That 15 seconds for 15 images is now less than 3 seconds.  Thus began my search for a image->base64 solution that worked in IE7/8.

---

Here are some additional requirements/restrictions:

- The solution cannot have external dependencies (i.e. $.getImageData).
- It needs to be 100% encapsulated so it can be portable.
- The source and quantity of images are variable, and they must be in URL format (base64 data up front is not an option).

I hope I've provided sufficient information and I appreciate any direction you're able to give.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert image to base64 without canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310997/convert-image-to-base64-without-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the FlashCanvas, fxCanvas or excanvas libraries, which simulate canvas using Flash or VML in old internet explorer versions. I believe all of these provide the `toDataURL` method from the Canvas API, allowing you to get an encoded representation of your image.

After extensive digging around (I'm in the same fix) I believe this is the only solution, short of writing a PHP script that you can send the image to. The problem with that of course is that there isn't a way to send images to the PHP script unless any of these three conditions is true:

- The browser supports typed arrays (`Uint8Array`)
- The browser supports `sendAsBinary`
- The image is being uploaded by someone via a form (in which case it can be sent to a PHP script that responds with the base 64 encoding)