# Base64 - Invalid Encoding

Tags: javascript, base64

I try to convert my image binary to base64 using this code but still not successful.

I got invalid base64 string. Verify using this tool.

http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');

function getBase64Image(img) {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

These solutions did not help me:

- [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)
- [How to convert an image to base64 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644035/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-in-javascript)
- [Convert image to base64 without canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310997/convert-image-to-base64-without-canvas)

Result
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

Comment: What is 'not successful' - is it erroring, giving an invalid base64 string, or something else?

Comment: invalid base64 string.

Comment: I don't think you can just remove the data:image part. Try just returning the dataURL before the replace.

Comment: already done before, still same

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Can you post the base64 string that you're getting (before the `replace` on the last line)?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Using the tool you suggest, that string decoded fine with no error.

Comment: With your string I got a 300x150 transparent png. What you expected to get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", img, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
    if (arrayBuffer) {
        var x = img.split('.');
        var ext = x[x.length - 1];
        var b64img = _arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer);
        $('<img />').attr('src', 'data:image/' + ext + ';base64,' + b64img).appendTo($('body'));
    }
};

oReq.send(null);

function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = ''
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}
```